# Properties of associates in an integral domain (Ring theory)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was asked to show the following three exercises for applications to understanding PID is UFD, however, I am struggling a little bit with the third one

Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of an integral domain $R$. Then

(1) $(a) \subseteq (b)$ if and only if $b|a$

The principal ideal $(b)$ consists of all multiples of $b$ thus $a \in (b) \iff b|a$

So if $(a) \subseteq (b)$ then $a$ is in the ideal $(b)$ so $b|a$

To show the converse, if $b|a$ then $a \in (b)$ which implies that every multiple of $a$ is also in $(b)$, therefore $(a) \subseteq (b) \ QED$

(2) $(a)=(b)$ if and only if $b|a$ and $a|b$

$(a)=(b)$ if and only if $(a) \subseteq (b)$ and $(b) \subseteq (a)$ so from 1) $(a) \subseteq (b)$ if and only if $b|a$ and $(b) \subseteq (a)$ if and only if $a|b \ QED$

(3) $(a) \subsetneq (b)$ if and only if $b|a$ and $b$ is not an associate of $a$

(this is where I am a little bit lost, but I have got the hint that if I can show that $a|b$ and $b|a$ if and only if $b$ is an associate of $a$, and then use 1) and 2) then it should be possible.

Comment: In part (3), do you mean $(a) \not \subseteq (b)$ or $(a) \subsetneq (b)$?  Because things get a lot easier if it's the latter of these two you intend.  Note that the $\LaTeX$ for "$\not \subseteq$" is "\not \subseteq" whereas that for "$\subsetneq$" is "\subsetneq".

Comment: So in $\Bbb Z$ we have $(3)\not\subseteq (7)$ iff $7|3$ and ... ?

Comment: thanks for hinting me this I couldnt find the latter one I will edit now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Suppose $(a)\subseteq(b)$; in particular $a\in(b)$, so $b\mid a$. Conversely, suppose $b\mid a$, with $a=bx$; if $r=as\in(a)$ then $r=bxs$ and therefore $r\in(b)$. Hence $(a)\subseteq(b)$.

<sup>Your idea is good, but it should be written out in greater detail.</sup>

(2) This follows from (1); indeed $(a)=(b)$ is the same as “$(a)\subseteq(b)$ and $(b)\subseteq(a)$”. Thus $b\mid a$ and $a\mid b$.

> **Note.** The condition “$b\mid a$ and $a\mid b$” implies $a$ and $b$ are associate. Indeed, $b=ax$ and $a=by$ for some $x$ and $y$. Therefore $a=axy$ and so $a(xy-1)=0$. Since $R$ is a domain, either $a=0$ (and so also $b=0$) or $xy=1$, implying $x$ is invertible.
>
> <sup>Conversely, if $a$ and $b$ are associate, then $(a)=(b)$ because of (1).</sup>

(3) Follows from (2) and the note: if $(a)\subsetneq(b)$, then $b\mid a$; but $b$ cannot be associate to $a$, otherwise $(a)=(b)$. You should be able to do the converse.

Comment: I know this might be late but how do you get to ''$a=axy$ and so  $a(xy−1)=0$''

Comment: @Djhoe If $b=ax$ and $a=by$, then $a=(ax)y=axy$. Therefore $axy-a=0$ and so $a(xy-1)=0$.

Comment: will it not be sufficient to just cancel a after showing a=axy, thus xy=1 and then it implies that both x and y are units?

Comment: @Djhoe You can do it when $a\ne0$, so the case $a=0$ has to be treated separately as I do; if $a=0$ then also $b=0$ and the two elements are indeed associate.

Comment: Sorry, but I am still a little bit confused about your last part of the proof after a(xy-1)=0. If a=0 then b also =0 because and because x is invertible a and b are associates I'm not quite sure about this part

Comment: @Djhoe If $a=0$ we're done. Otherwise $xy-1=0$, so $xy=1$ and therefore $x$ is invertible.

Comment: And since x is invertible both x and y are units?

Comment: @Djhoe Unit=invertible

Comment: And then same way show y is invertible?

Comment: @Djhoe Of course, if $xy=1$, then $y=x^{-1}$ and $x=y^{-1}$.